# Tableview bounce back to content offset

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableview with a Pull-to-refresh style textview offset 50px above the table. When you drag the tableview down, the textview becomes visible. What I want to make happen is that when you pull far enough, upon releasing, the tableview animates only back to the position where the textview is fully visible. Essentially, I want it to animate back to a content offset of -50. When I try adding: `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -50) animated:YES];` into the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` delegate method, the table seems to jump before returning back to it's original content offset of 0,0. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a little unclear. Which way does it jump?

Comment: The jump is just a small movement downwards before scrolling back up to it's original position. It seems clear that my call to setContentOffset is getting registered and then immediately getting overriden by the default behavior of the tableview to scroll back when stretched. Hope this helps.

Comment: The way to do it is set the tableView's content inset top to the position you want.  You can do that in an animation block. Do you really want a textView up there?  How about a UILabel?

Comment: danh, Thanks so much! This achieved the desired effect exactly how I wanted it to happen. In reality, I do have a UILabel up there and I add the textView after the user releases. If you want to paste that into an answer, I'd be glad to choose it. Thanks again, I really appreciate the help!